# SAS Do Loop is Omitting Rows in Processing

Tags: sas, do-loops, datastep

I have the following code. I am trying to test a paragraph (descr) for a list of keywords (key_words). When I execute this code, the log reads in all the variables for the array, but will only test 2 of the 20,000 rows in the do loop (do i=1 to 100 and on). Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

```
data JE.KeywordMatchTemp1;
  set JE.JEMasterTemp end=eof;
  if _n_ = 1 then do i = 1 by 1 until (eof);
    set JE.KeyWords;
    array keywords[100] $30 _temporary_;
    keywords[i] = Key_Words;
  end;
  match = 0;
  do i = 1 to 100;
    if index(descr, keywords[i]) then match = 1;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `end=eof` is in the wrong place.

This is a trivial example calculating the 'rank' of the age value for each `SASHELP.CLASS` respondent.

See where I put the `end=eof`.  That's because you need to use it to control the array filling operation.  Otherwise, what happens is your loop that is `do i = 1 to eof;` doesn't really do what you're saying it should: it's not actually terminating at `eof` since that is never true (as it is defined in the *first* `set` statement).  Instead it terminates because you reach beyond the end of the dataset, which is specifically what you don't want.

That's what the `end=eof` is doing: it's preventing you from trying to pull a row when the array filling dataset is finished, which terminates the whole data step.  Any time you see a data step terminate after exactly 2 iterations, you can be confident that's what the problem is likely to be - it is a very common issue.

```
data class_ranks;
  set sashelp.class;   *This dataset you are okay iterating over until the end of the dataset and then quitting the data step, like a normal data step.;
  array ages[19] _temporary_; 
  if _n_=1 then do;
    do _i = 1 by 1 until (eof);   *iterate until the end of the *second* set statement;
      set sashelp.class end=eof;  *see here? This eof is telling this loop when to stop.  It is okay that it is not created until after the loop is.;
      ages[_i] = age;
    end;
    call sortn(of ages[*]);   *ordering the ages loaded by number so they are in proper order for doing the trivial rank task;
  end;
  age_rank = whichn(age,of ages[*]);  *determine where in the list the age falls.  For a real version of this task you would have to check whether this ever happens, and if not you would have to have logic to find the nearest point or whatnot.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing if you can. It appears the DO-LOOP I have in the second part of the code is not stopping when the condition is met. Any reason that might be happening?

Comment: Not stopping when `i=100` ? Or not stopping when `match=1`?  The latter is not going to stop it, why would it?